# date_add or date_sub speed difference?

Tags: php, mysql

Given the following two mysql queries:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE DATE_ADD(datetimecolumn,INTERVAL 24 HOUR)>NOW()
```

And

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 24 HOUR)>datetimecolumn
```

Which query will be faster?

Comment: I vote second one is faster as it would do date_sub on now() and not each record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What I think you want to know:

The second ought to be appreciably faster, since `datetimecolumn` may be directly used in an index operation. Without an index, I'd say the difference ought to be negligible (time operation and function calls being too much faster than data retrieval from disk).

### What you really asked:

The two queries are not equivalent (they do not return the same records).

```
DATE_ADD(datetimecolumn,INTERVAL 24 HOUR)>NOW()
```

retrieves the records NEWER than 24 hours from now (so, all those inserted since yesterday).

The second

```
DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 24 HOUR)>datetimecolumn
```

retrieves the records OLDER than 24 hours from now (two or more days in the past).

So in that case, which query is the faster, the answer would be **it depends on how many records there are...**

Answer (score 1):

The below will be fast.

The below one could apply the index of `datetimecolumn`, while the above one could not.

`DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 24 HOUR)` only need to be calculated once, while `DATE_ADD(datetimecolumn,INTERVAL 24 HOUR)` need to do with every records.